# how to prevent opening a tooltip simultaneously in the presence of mapped values?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[image]

Those "avg" components are the result of a .map (): my problem is that when I go to do the onMouseOver on a certain component, all the tooltips open at the same time! How to avoid this? This is my code:

```
{evaluations.filter((item: Assessment) => item.data?.interview?.id === interview.item.id && item.data?.status?.name === StatusNameEnum.CLOSED).map((value: Assessment) =>
                value.evaluation?.fitToJob?.suggestedProfiles?.map((element: SuggestedProfile, index: number) =>
                    <Grid container item lg={12} className="mb-16" justifyContent="space-between">
                        <Grid item lg={11} md={10} sm={11} xs={10}>
                            <Typography className="average-style">{element.family?.name + " / " + element.specialization?.name}</Typography>
                        </Grid>

                        <Grid
                            key={index}
                            className="position-relative"
                            item lg={1}
                            onMouseOver={() => showSuggestedProfileTooltip(true)}
                            onMouseLeave={() => showSuggestedProfileTooltip(false)}
                        >
                            {suggestedProfileTooltip &&
                                <AssessmentFitToJobTooltip
                                    evaluations={evaluations}
                                    interview={interview}
                                />
                            }
                            <Typography className="average-style">{`Avg: ${element.evaluation}`}</Typography>
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                ))}
```

Comment: how would `showSuggestedProfileTooltip` which one to show? show the code for that function

Comment: const [suggestedProfileTooltip, showSuggestedProfileTooltip] = useState<boolean>(false)...is simply an internal state with react Hook

Comment: oh, some react mumbo ... why would it know which tooltip to show or not? I mean, clearly it does not

Comment: so there is a way to avoid this?

Comment: sorry, I know enough about reactjs to know that I don't like it :p I don't understand how a call to some function could a) show the tooltip and b) know which one to show ... there must be some code somewhere